# how to open url in other browser using adaptive card in microsoft teams bot?

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using microsoft teams bot framework and I want a adaptive card with a button to open url in popout(other browser) 
By using (Actions.openUrl) it Opens a URL in the default browser.
and want it to open in other browser

This is what i have tried and I am using node.js

```
var card = {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [{
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": `${session.message.text}`,
            "weight": "bolder",
            "size": "medium"
        }

        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "url": `${bodyData.img}`

    },

    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": `${bodyData.calendar}`,
            "wrap": true
        }]
    }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.openUrl",
            "title": "Open in Popout",
            "url": `${bodyData.url}`
        }   
        ]};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like paul cheung said, you cannot specify the browser in an `openUrl` button. Not only that, you cannot specify the URL's "target" in an `openUrl` button. You can see [here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.OpenUrl.html) that the only thing you can specify is the URL itself. The details of how the URL gets opened are the responsibility of the client and the bot has no control over them.

I think you have a few options.

### Option 1

If you really want to open a browser window like a popup, you can try creating a sort of redirect page that the card would link to. When the user clicks the button, your redirect page would open in a new tab of the current browser window and then whatever client-side code you've set up would open the target page in a new window and close the redirect page's tab.

### Option 2

The conventional way to do what you're talking about in Teams is to use a [task module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview). Depending on what your URL contains, you might even consider putting a card in your task module instead of a web page.

Comment: Option 2 is something i was looking for, Thanks it will help.

Comment: @gauravdhingra - Please remember to accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

This action type specifies a URL to launch in the **default browser**, You can NOT specify the browser at moment. BTW, the default browser is a system level setting(default program) as you know.

**Update:**
like Kyle said, if task module is your option, [Here](https://github.com/Office365DevOps/msteams-samples-task-module-csharp) is a repository you can take a quick look, it includes all necessary code. popout window was triggered in javascript and adaptive card.

Comment: I don't want to specify the browser , I want my link to open in a popout. Like it opens when we use Action.signin

Comment: or new window of same browser

Comment: @gauravdhingra - Your question asks how to open a URL in "other browser." If you meant to ask how to open a URL in a new window then you should have said "a new window" instead.

Comment: @KyleDelaney yeah True That , Thanks I'll take care of it in future.